# the definition of "Birational Equivalence"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have confused with the definition of "Birational Equivalence" in the Algebraic Geometry.

In My Text book ,  ($V$ and $W$ are irreducible quasi-projective varieties)

A rational map $f : V \to W$ is called birational
 if there is a rational map $g : W \to V$  with

$f\circ g = \text{id}_W$ and 
$g\circ f=\text{id}_V$.

---

My question is the domain of $\text{id}_W$ and $\text{id}_V$.

How do we think the domain of these rational map?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on what it might mean?

Answer (score 5):

A rational map does not have a domain. A rational map is an *equivalence class* of regular maps: Let $V$ be a variety. Then a rational map is an equivalence class of pairs $(\phi_U,U)$ where $\phi:U \to W$ is a regular map and $U \subset V$ is an open subset. We say that two such pairs are *equivalent* if $\phi_U = \phi_{U'}$ on $U \cap U'$.

With this definition in mind, we say that two rational maps are **equal** if they agree on a dense open set. Thus the domain of $id_W, id_V$ are the whole of $W,V$, but the equality sign means "equal as rational maps".

Comment: sorry for the late reply. thank you!